# java file reading: not reading(displaying whole file)

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

when i run the bufferReader on small file it works fine but when i ran it on a large file (100,000+) it did not display all it contents. when i ran it through the debugger it showed the lines where displayed but disappeared for some reason do you no why?
(tried a few different example but still get the game result)

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("NumFile.txt"));
    String line;


    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
```

Comment: Are you running it inside your IDE? Your IDE may be rate-limiting the output to the console. Try running it on the command line. This code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Define 'displayed but disappeared'. The code you posted reads the entire file.

Comment: thank for the help turned out to be the IDE

Answer (score -2):

use java8 in this regard

code

`try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
  lines.forEachOrdered(line -> process(line));
}`

to print lines code

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
lines.forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
  }
```

Hope my help would be useful keep coding.